# Onde coloco esse código iframe pra funcionar o player?

Tags: html, xml, iframe, blogger

Meu blog ta possuído pelo demônio da programação,e nao tem jeito de funcionar...
Tenho esse código do player:

E tenho que por o player no blog, vou deixar o código nesse site, quem quiser me ajudar e mandar esse demônio de volta pras profundezas... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7lrOPUelxG0LXdMMWNqWkR3NEU/view

Comment: <iframe src="http://player.srvstm.com/player-barra/9188/000000" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="31"></iframe>

Comment: Sim, nao pode? foi mal novo por aqui

Comment: tem um link dentro desse template que o navegador deu como perigoso https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNb5y.png

Comment: não pode, aguarde até que alguém capacitado te ajude a resolver o seu problema na outra publicação que você fez. E sempre coloque seu código aqui. Força alguém que quer te ajudar a acessar um link externo é complicado. @LeoCaracciolo toma cuidado..

Comment: Eu tentei postar aqui! mas ficou td bugado... é um texto esse código

Comment: qual é o endereço da pagina que vc quer colocar o player?

Comment: https://vdfvdvdrf.blogspot.com.br

Comment: já tentou colocar dentro de uma div? tipo <div class='titlewrapper'><iframe .....</iframe>

Comment: eu tinha visto em um tutorial um assim: <div id='floatLayer2' style='position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; height:0px; width:90px'>
<iframe frameborder='0' height='40' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='No' src='http://player.srvstm.com/player-barra/9188/000000' width='1500'/>
</div>
botei antes do </body> e nao apareceu nada.. nao deu erro de código mas nao apareceu nada

Comment: entendi, mas tenta colocar dentro de uma div que já existe